# SUDS SOAP WSDL not working with Vormetric Appliance

Tags: python, python-2.7, suds

I am trying to use Jerko SUDS to generate WSDL client calls to a Vormetric key server, to show the keys on the platform. I am using SUDS elements to construct the SOAP message.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.element import Element
import ssl
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = 'https://<dkm>/communication-server/SSControllerCli?wsdl'
client = Client(url)

login = Element('loginInfo')
user = Element('userName').setText('xxx')
auth = Element('password').setText('xxx')
domain = Element('domainName').setText('xxx')
keyType = Element('switchKey').setText('All')
login.append(user)
login.append(auth)
login.append(domain)

result = client.service.ShowAllKeys(login, keyType)
print result
```

When I execute this it appears to work, and generate a good SOAP message, however I get a server error when trying to execute.

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://<dkm>/communication-server/SSControllerCli)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.vormetric.com/securityserver/clicommon/2010/02/26" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="htt
p://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:ShowAllKeys>
         <loginInfo>
            <userName>xxx</userName>
            <password>xxx</password>
            <domainName>xxx</domainName>
         </loginInfo>
         <switchKey>All</switchKey>
      </ns0:ShowAllKeys>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': '""', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
DEBUG:suds.client:HTTP failed - 500 - Internal Server Error:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>An internal error oc
curred on the Security Server. Refer to cgss.log and server.log for details. Call support if necessary.</faultstring><detail><CgssServerFaultDetail xmlns="http:
//www.vormetric.com/securityserver/clicommon/2010/02/26"><servername>***REMOVED***</servername><errorcode>DAO0038E</errorcode><errormessage>A
n internal error occurred on the Security Server. Refer to cgss.log and server.log for details. Call support if necessary.</errormessage></CgssServerFaultDetail
></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
ERROR:suds.client:<suds.sax.document.Document instance at 0x0000000003E0BA48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vorm-soap-suds.py", line 29, in <module>
    result = client.service.ShowAllKeys(login, keyType)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\suds\client.py", line 619, in send
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\suds\client.py", line 670, in process_reply
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'An internal error occurred on the Security Server. Refer to cgss.log and server.log for details. Call support if necessary.
'
```

The interesting thing is that I know that the message structure itself is good, because I can drop it into the Chrome Wizdler app and it works perfectly, so it appears to be an issue specific to SUDS.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Been running into this problem myself. This probably has to do with the envelope/namespace being used, which is not current any longer.
Talking about this one:
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
When validating your XML, I get this:

Element Envelope@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ is not a valid Envelope@http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope document or a valid substitution.